# UTL_FILE.FOPEN fails with ORA-29283: invalid file operation in SQL*PLUS works from SQL Developer

Tags: sql, oracle

I am running Oracle 12c on an Exadata box running Oracle linux.  We are using pluggable databases.

I have a password verify function that reads a dictionary file to compare against the user's proposed password change.  This works when I invoke 'password' from SQL Developer 4.x, but not from SQL*Plus remoted into the Exadata box using MobaXterm.

These errors come back in SQL*Plus:

```
ORA-28003: password verification for the specified password failed

ORA-29283: invalid file operation

ORA-29283: invalid file operation
ORA-06512: at "SYS.FINDINDICTIONARY", line 43 

( this is the function that reads the file)  

ORA-06512: at "SYS.GGATE_VERIFY_FUNCTION", line 242 

(my password verification function)   

ORA-06512: at line 1

Line 43 in SYS.FINDINDICTIONARY IS 
 f := UTL_FILE.FOPEN('SBCTCLOGINSECURITY','dictionaryWords','R')
```

;

I did run the CREATE DIRECTORY statement in Oracle.  I don't see an init.ora file being used on the box.  We didn't set it up.

The 'SBCTCLOGINSECURITY directory exists in the OS and in Oracle, users seem
to have permissions:
Here are results of queries:

```
SELECT OWNER, DIRECTORY_NAME, DIRECTORY_PATH, ORIGIN_CON_ID FROM ALL_DIRECTORIES;

SYS SBCTCLOGINSECURITY  /home/oracle/sbctcLoginSecurity 6

SELECT GRANTOR, GRANTEE, TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME, PRIVILEGE, TYPE FROM all_tab_privs   WHERE table_name LIKE 'SBCTCLOGINSECURITY';

SYS PUBLIC  SYS SBCTCLOGINSECURITY  READ    DIRECTORY

SYS PUBLIC  SYS SBCTCLOGINSECURITY  WRITE   DIRECTORY
```

In linux the permissions look OK.  This is permissions on /home/oracle/sbctcLoginSecurity

```
[oracle@xd01dbadm01 ~]$ -rw-rw-rw- 1 oracle oinstall 3218521 Apr 14 15:32 dictionaryWords
```

this is permissions on the file:

```
-rw-rw-rw- 1 oracle oinstall 3218521 Apr 14 15:32 dictionaryWords
```

In my searching I found a suggestion to run

```
SELECT value FROM v$parameter WHERE name='utl_file_dir';
```

This comes back null and I don't know why. I tried adding it in my pluggable database and got an error saying it wasn't allowed in a pluggable database.  At the parent database level it didn't make the error go away.  I am waiting for an Oracle restart to see if that makes difference.

Any suggestions from real Oracle people would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is it a single instance, or RAC and you're hitting a different node now (and the files doesn't exist on both nodes)?

Comment: Yep, that's it.  The directory and the file doesn't exist on node 2.  Thanks Alex!